# angular-phonecat upgrading from 1.x : error Failed to load template: app/phone-list/phone-list.template.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

Hi I'm using this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#) to lean how to migrate from Angular1 to Angular2.

At the end of the [step 4 Upgrading the Phone Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-the-phone-service), when I want to check the running application with "npm start", i got this error :

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/phone-list/phone-list.template.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a typo error in the online tutorial.

In the file *app/phone-list/phone-list.component.ts*
change the line :

```
templateUrl: ‘app/phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
```

by

```
templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
```