# angular-phonecat upgrading from 1.x : error Unknown provider: phoneProvider <- phone

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I'm using this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#) to lean how to migrate from Angular1 to Angular2.

At the end of the [step 4 Upgrading the Phone Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-the-phone-service),

after fix [typo error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592472/angular-phonecat-upgrading-from-1-x-error-failed-to-load-template-app-phone-l),

when I want to check the running application with "npm start", I got this error :

```
Unknown provider: phoneProvider <- phone
```

You can reproduce this error by cloning my GitHub repository that contains all the steps of this tutorial:

```
git clone https://github.com/ltrillaud/angular-phonecat.git
git co 12866b6ba3ab82bd3fbe0a692f55bacac91040b2
```

I expect to have an application running in hybrid mode with Angular2 services inside an Angular1 application.

Answer (score 0):

The document is not so perfect, you know, what you need to do is add a declaration after the bootstrap:

`upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['phonecatApp']).ready((ref) => {
  let phone: Phone = ref.ng1Injector.get('phone');
});`

https://github.com/angular/upgrade-builds/blob/master/src/upgrade_adapter.d.ts#L322